# Type Mapping of MongoDB using Spring Boot

Tags: spring

I am using a Spring boot project along with MongoDB. Now my problem is that I have a field ID and Mongo also autogenerates an objectId _id. Now i will call an get API with /{id} and the result will be available by findById(). But for that I have to map _id with id so as to fetch the specific result. Please have a look at the data attached as image below and revert back.

[MonogoDB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw3lN.png)

Answer (score 0):

What your POJO looks like?
Is there:

```
...

    @Id
    String id;
    int ID;
...
```

You can use just `@Id String id` without integers id.
With annotation @Id MongoDB will understand that it is the _id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `@Field("_id")` to get mapped MongoDB collection `'_id'` field as below,

```
@Field("_id")
String id;
```